# How to use global planner package in hydro-devel navigation?

Tags: ros, navigation, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a newer and have been learning the book of <> .I have tried the gazebo turtlebot_simulation package and also realised navigation using iRobot and hokuyo in Fuerte and Groovy distribution . I found global planner package using A*  algorithm contained in the hydro distribution and hope to have a try.

But i don't know how to change the default "navfn/NavfnROS" object for the param base_global_planner in move_base package .In old navfn package ,class NavfnROS is defined with parameters like /allow_unknown contained in initialization function.I learn that the global planner package can subscribe for the navfn package. however, how to use your param so as to get the plan like befor  ?

Your suggestion would  be appreciated ,thank you@David Lu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171306/how-to-use-global-planner-package-in-hydro-devel-navigation?/) by [breeze](https://answers.ros.org/users/18466/breeze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [breeze](https://answers.ros.org/users/18466/breeze/) on 2014-05-29**:
@David Lu Look forwards to your attention and furthermore advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this all you want to know?
For example,

move_base.launch.xml

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/velocity_smoother.launch.xml"/>
  &ltinclude file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/safety_controller.launch.xml"/>

  <arg name="odom_topic" default="odom" />
  <arg name="map_topic" default="/map" />
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="/base_scan" />

 <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner" /> 
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
&ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
&ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
&ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/eband_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" /> 
    <param name="global_costmap/map_topic" value="$(arg map_topic)" />
    <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@KEN_IN_JAPAN is correct in that changing which algorithm is used is as easy as changing the base_global_planner variable. To use global_planner, just change the value to global_planner/GlobalPlanner

Allow_unknown is still a parameter as documented here:
http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-14**:
@David Lu, Thanks for your comment on changing the value to global_planner/GlobalPlanner!